# The difference between "on" and just using "hover"

Tags: jquery

Can someone please explain to me why this code works:

```
$(".landing-story").hover(function(){
            $(this).find(".cover").slideToggle();
        });
```

And this code does not work:

```
$(".landing-story").on("hover",function(){
            $(this).find(".cover").slideToggle();
        });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no actual `"hover"` event - `.hover()` is a shorthand function for adding a `mouseenter` and (optionally) a `mouseleave` handler. This code should work like you expect:

```
$(".landing-story").on("mouseenter",function(){
    $(this).find(".cover").slideToggle();
});
```

Edit: As Kevin Panko points out, `.hover()` will always assign both a `mouseenter` and a `mouseleave` event handler, which can be the same function or two different ones, depending on whether it's passed one or two functions.

Comment: So would the first option of using hover() be the preferred method for doing this?

Comment: @Richard you can select him as best answer with the green tick if it solved your question

Comment: It did work, but I need to wait a few more minutes before it lets me.

Comment: @thenewseattle: True enough, but so would sticking with `.hover()`. I think the question was less about fixing code and more about understanding it.

Comment: I get the impression that using "on" is the best practice for this?

Comment: To be nitpicky -- `.hover()` actually handles both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` all the time.  The *optional* part is you can supply one function to handle both, or two separate functions.

Comment: @Richard: Not especially. The shorthand functions are there for a reason, and 99% of the time they'll do just fine. Only time I'd think about using `.on()` is if I wanted to assign one function to a bunch of events at once.

Comment: @Richard The `.on()` function should be avoided when possible, as it is just more typing for no reason.

Comment: @Richard it seems using on is not a good practice. simply stick with this example http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseenter_mouseleave

Comment: @thenewseattle: Well, sure, if the question hadn't specifically been about using `.on()`.

Comment: @Richard You might want to take comments about not using `on()` with a grain of salt.  Use of `on()` is a bit of a different paradigm than other event handling functions and provides very powerful (and easy to misuse) capabilities.  If for example you want to attach handlers for events on elements that do not yet exist in the DOM (for example they are dynamically added) you MUST use `on()` (either that or specifically add event handlers to these elements after they have been added). You should however REALLY read the documentation and fully understand event delegation before use.

Answer (score 4):

There is no event called `hover`, see this [section of the documentation for `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> *Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9:* The name `"hover"` used as a
>   shorthand for the string `"mouseenter mouseleave"`. It attaches a *single
>   event handler* for those two events, and the handler must examine
>   `event.type` to determine whether the event is `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`.
>   Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method,
>   which accepts *one or two* functions.

Just stick with the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method, or you could use this, which is the same thing:

```
$(".landing-story").on("mouseenter mouseleave",function(){
    $(this).find(".cover").slideToggle();
});
```